# Accessing private properties through method

Tags: php

I have a class like this:

```
class myclass {

  private $a;
  private $b;

  public function dosomething($a,$b) {
    $this->a = $a;
    $this->b = $b;
  }

}
```

I want to return the properties a and b so they can be only be accessed through

```
myclass->dosomething->a
```

If I set the properties to public they can be accessed through myclass->a but they will be empty until dosomething() is called, so there is no requirement to call them. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What are you asking? Can you make more specific question?

Comment: Just make `dosomething` return the values as an object or array.

Comment: If I return as an object from within the method I get the error Undefined property: stdClass::$a

Comment: How are you returning it?

Comment: Have you tried placing the init of variables in the constructor? Also if you want multiple levels, just go for an assoc array.

Comment: What I want to do is return a and b and be able to access through dosomething() as properties. So I can refer to them like dosomething()->a dosomething()->b

Comment: You can always return an array and access them as dosomething()['a'].

Comment: @DavidChen: That syntax only works in PHP 5.4+

Comment: My bad. Have you also tried placing an argument in dosomething? Ex: dosomething('a')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have your function return an object.

```
public function dosomething($a,$b) {
    $this->a = $a;
    $this->b = $b;

    return (object)array(
        'a' => $this->a,
        'b' => $this->$b
    );
}
```

Then you can access it as you were trying to:

```
echo $obj->dosomething(1, 2)->a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Amend your function to return the values as an array (as has been mentioned in the comments)

```
public function dosomething($a = null,$b = null) {
  if (!is_null($a)) $this->a = $a;
  if (!is_null($b)) $this->b = $b;
  return array('a' => $a, 'b' => $b);
}
```

Then depending on which version of PHP you are using

```
//=> 5.4 - which allows object method array dereferencing
$class->doSomething()['a']; 

//< 5.4 - which does not
$array = $class->doSomething();
$a = $array['a'];
```

I've added the `null` options to your method params and handled it in the method to allow you to call `doSomething` without params when you are just wanting a return value